# Motor undervoltage

Tags: power, motor, undervoltage

In the situation of a motor losing voltage, say it's rated for 240vac, but it's only receiving 190vac, what happens in terms of the power triangle? Does current increase, does it slow down and reduce impedance, and just run at less power?

Comment: What kind of motor is this? Induction motor? Commutator motor?

Answer (score 1):

An electrical machine will draw what current is required to satisfy the load (P =Tw)

For light load a reduction in terminal voltage will not really affect the output shaft performance.

However... With increased load and reduced voltage the rotor velocity will drop while the shaft load torque is opposed.

At some point the electrical machine will stall or fail to breakout if at rest

Comment: Ok, so with small change current will increase?

Comment: Yes as power in = power out. So a reduction in supply volts will be matched with an increase in supply current for no change in static output (dynamic will be affected). At some point though the output will be affected even for static characteristics

Answer (score 0):

As a motor slows down (any motor, not just yours), its back EMF will drop, which allows it to run at a lower feed voltage because back EMF opposes the feed voltage.  Or, given the same feed voltage, causes it to draw more current because the effective driving voltage [feed_voltage - back_EMF] is increased, assuming so far that its impedance is constant.

As the frequency in the windings decreases, the impedance also drops, which causes it to draw more current at a particular effective driving voltage [feed_voltage - back_EMF].

For motors that have synchronously switched windings (PMDC, BLDC, stepper, etc.), their frequency is controlled directly by speed or vice-versa and so the effects combine under load with constant feed voltage.  For motors that are asynchronously switched (induction), the impedance is somewhat independent of speed.

However, you're talking about reducing the feed voltage.  That will necessarily reduce the unloaded speed.  As speed decreases, the impedance may or may not decrease, depending on the type of motor (see above).  As speed decreases, the required torque may or may not change in one direction or the other, depending on the type of load.

Instantaneous torque is determined by current, which itself is determined by [[feed_voltage - back_EMF] / impedance].  Maximum theoretical speed (assuming no torque consumed by bearings, air resistance, etc.) is determined simply by the feed voltage because it's opposed by the back EMF, which itself is determined by speed.

Of course, all of that is also affected by the motor's internal geometry, so you can't really compare them directly.  For example, more poles tend to produce more torque and less speed, all else being equal.

Answer (score 0):

This excerpt from the [TECO Australia MAX E3 motor catalogue](http://www.teco.com.au/assets/Catalogue/EMD/TECO-MAX-E3-H66-Catalogue-TECOE3-H66-022013.pdf) outlines the effects of reduced voltage on a 3-phase 415 VAC induction motor. I would imagine similar effects apply to a 1-phase 240VAC induction motor.

The interesting thing is that torque (i.e. power) decreases as the **square** of voltage. At 190 VAC, your 240 VAC motor is only getting 79% voltage, i.e. 62% torque. If 62% torque is not enough to keep your load turning, your motor will either run at reduced speed, or it will stall.

[image]